# Get list of IDs not present in table

Tags: mysql, arrays, select

Say I have a list of ids, e.g. (1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 86), and a table with a column id. I want to find all of the numbers in my list where there is not a matching row.

i.e. if the mysql table was like this:

```
id  letter
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
```

And I have the list `(1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 86)`, I want a query that will return `(9, 86)`.

The only thing I can think of, is to build a really big virtual table, like:

```
select 1 as n union select 3 as n union select 9 as n union ....
```

Which I can then join against. Is there a better way? I would like to be able to do this all within mysql. As a side note (although I don't expect it to be relevant), my table has around 10,000 rows, and the list I'm using has ~100 numbers in it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first `create` a table that will contain the elements of the **LIST**

i.e `(1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 86)`

```
create table t
(
    num int
)
insert into t
values
(1),(3),(9),(2),(4),(86)
```

Now you can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT num
FROM t
WHERE num not in (select id from letter_table);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0f9f/1)**

From **Comments**.
<s>**Edit:**</s>

There is a way in which you **don't** have to `create` a table

```
select N from
(select 1 as N
union all
select 3 as N
union all
select 9 as N
union all
select 2 as N
union all
select 4  as N
union all
select 86 as  N)t1
where t1.N
not in (select id from letter_table)
```

Please refer the **[New SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33ec9/1)**.

I think OP want's the **Edited** Part.

**P.S. Make Sure table t1 doesn't exists in your DB**

Comment: No, I wanted to avoid using a bunch of unions because I figured they would be slow, as well as requiring the list to be preprocessed; not sure what the most efficient solution is

Comment: In that case **Creating a Temp Table** is the most **efficient**

Comment: Just test the union vs. the temp table with your actual data rather than speculating. Both queries can be mostly generated with some text editor voodoo.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table which contains IDs and than you can do it eaasily. See a demonstration here

```
SELECT
  S.id,
  ''   AS `letter`
FROM sequence S
WHERE S.id NOT IN(SELECT
                    id
                  FROM mytable)
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

Comment: Ok, but then you have to create the table beforehand. I don't want a permanent table, so, how do I build the temporary table from the list as part of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the temp table or the `UNION` method in @Luv's answer, consider replacing the `NOT IN` with an outer join as it'll likely perform better (test with your actual environment & data, of course):

```
SELECT num
FROM t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN letter_table
        ON t.num = letter_table.id
WHERE letter_table.id IS NULL;
```

If you use the UNION method, replace `FROM t` with `FROM ([big UNION here]) t`.